# React: why is my cursor jumping to the end of the input field after the input is modified

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I made a component to format phone number from `XXXXXXXXXX` to `'(XXX) XXX-XXXX'`
here is my code

```js
function formatPhoneNumber(phone) {
  const area = phone.slice(0, 3);
  const first = phone.slice(3, 6);
  const second = phone.slice(6, 10);

  let formattedTelephoneNumber = phone;

  if (phone.length >= 1) {
    formattedTelephoneNumber = `(${formattedTelephoneNumber}`;
  }

  if (phone.length >= 4) {
    formattedTelephoneNumber = `(${area}) ${first}`;
  }

  if (phone.length >= 7) {
    formattedTelephoneNumber = `(${area}) ${first}-${second}`;
  }

  return formattedTelephoneNumber;
}

function getRawPhoneNumber(inputValue) {
  return [...inputValue].filter((char) => /\d/.test(char)).join("");
}

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const phoneNumber = getRawPhoneNumber(e.target.value);
    const formatted = formatPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);

    setValue(formatted);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input value={value} onChange={handleInputChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

It works ok but when you are typing in the middle of a string  - either add an extra number or delete one number, the cursor will jump to the end.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

here is a live demo you can play with
https://codesandbox.io/s/phone-number-format-x4nnk?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You receive the value entered by the user and generate a string with a **new format**. I suggest using `regex` for this

Comment: you can get the current position of the cursor before updating the value with e.target.selectionStart and after updating set cursor again